# Why is Java faster than C for matrix multiplication?

Tags: java, c, performance, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I wrote codes for multiplying matrices of huge sizes (such as 2000x2000) in Java and C to benchmark them as an activity. I cannot understand why Java code executes faster than C code...

*Here are the results:*

**Matrix 1 size:** 1000 x 500; **Matrix 2 size:** 500 x 1000

```
Time Taken by Java : 13787 ms
Time Taken by C: 20565 ms
```

**Matrix 1 size:** 1000 x 1000; **Matrix 2 size:** 1000 x 1500

```
Time Taken by Java : 64636 ms
Time Taken by C: 65155 ms
```

*Here are the codes I wrote:*

In C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX 10

int main()
{
    // Declaring the variables
    long i, j, k, m1, n1, m2, n2;

    // Reading the dimensions of the matrices
    printf("Enter the row dimension of the matrix 1:\t "); scanf("%ld", &m1);
    printf("Enter the column dimension of the matrix 1:\t "); scanf("%ld", &n1);
    printf("\nEnter the row dimension of the matrix 2:\t "); scanf("%ld", &m2);
    printf("Enter the column dimension of the matrix 2:\t "); scanf("%ld", &n2);

    // Variables used by the clock
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;

    // Necessary condition for matrix multiplication
    if (n1 != m2)
    {
        printf("\nMuliplication is not possible!\n");
        printf("Please check the dimensions of the matrices!\n\n");
    }

    else
    {
        char choice;
        start = clock();                                    // Starts the clock

        long (*mat1)[n1] = malloc(m1 * sizeof *mat1);       // Storing the matrix in heap memory
        if (mat1 == NULL) exit(1);                          // Freeing up space once matrix is NULL
            
        long (*mat2)[n2] = malloc(m2 * sizeof *mat2);
        if (mat2 == NULL) exit(1);
            
        long (*mat3)[n2] = malloc(m1 * sizeof *mat3);
        if (mat3 == NULL) exit(1);

        // Generating matrix with random elements
        for(i=0; i<m1; i++)
            for(j=0; j<n1; j++)
                mat1[i][j] = (long)rand()%MAX;

        // Generating matrix with random elements
        for(i=0; i<m2; i++)
            for(j=0; j<n2; j++)
                mat2[i][j] = (long)rand()%MAX;

    printf("\nMatrices Generated!\n");

        // Initializing the result matrix with zeroes        
        for(i=0; i<m1; i++)
            for(j=0; j<n2; j++)        
                mat3[i][j] = 0;

        // Performing mat1[m1][n1] x mat2[m2][n2] = mat3[m1][n2]
        for (i = 0; i < m1; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
                for (k = 0; k < m2; k++)
                    mat3[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
        
        // Freeing up space occupied by the matrices after process completion
        free(mat1); free(mat2); free(mat3);

        end = clock();                                                  // Stop the clock timer
        cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;      // Time taken by the program
        printf("\nMultiplication took %f milliseconds to execute.\n\n", cpu_time_used*1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In Java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Matrix {
    private static String s;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        // Reading the dimensions of matrix 1
        System.out.print("Enter the row dimension of the matrix 1:\t ");
        int m1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.print("Enter the column dimension of the matrix 1:\t ");
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        // Reading the dimensions of matrix 2
        System.out.print("\nEnter the row dimension of the matrix 2:\t ");
        int m2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.print("Enter the column dimension of the matrix 2:\t ");
        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        // Print error message if condition not satisfied
        if(n1 != m2) {
            System.out.println("\nMuliplication is not possible!");
            System.out.println("Please check the dimensions of the matrices!\n");
        }

        else {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            // Declaring matrices
            int[][] matrix1 = new int[m1][n1];
            int[][] matrix2 = new int[m2][n2];

            // Generate random matrices
            generateRandom(matrix1);
            generateRandom(matrix2);

            System.out.println("\nMatrices Generated!\n");

            // Performs matrix1 x matrix2 = result
            int[][] result = new int[m1][n2];
            for (int i = 0; i < m1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < n1; k++) {
                        result[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
                    }
                }
            }
            
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            s = "Execution time is " + (end - start);
            System.out.print(s + " milliseconds.\n\n");
        }
    }

    private static void displayMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        int r = matrix.length;
        int c = matrix[0].length;

        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    // Generates Random Matrices
    private static void generateRandom(int[][] matrix) {
        int r = matrix.length;
        int c = matrix[0].length;
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                // Gives numbers in range (0,10)
                matrix[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running these on Windows 10, with Latest Versions of MinGW and JDK.

Comment: You are not comparing matrix multiplication. You are comparing matrix creation, generation, multiplication and deletion. So its not a fair comparison. Compare the time of only matrix multiplication method.

Comment: Do not use *loop* for initialize result matrix in `c` . Just use `memset`;

Comment: Are you using `-o3` ?

Comment: Java is never faster than C do you hear me? NEVER! Just kidding :), is it possible that you are reserving dynamic memory more often in your C code? that's a big bottleneck. On the other hand, in the C code I count 4 loop blocks and in Java only 3. Also, are you compiling with optimizations?

Comment: In the C code: Instead of initializing `mat3` in a loop, you should allocate it using `calloc`. Then you don't need the loop. (and as other have mention - make sure to compile the C code with -O3)

Comment: Did you compile the C program with optimizations?  On my i7-7700k, your program claims it took 470ms when compiled with `-O3` (for the 1000x500 test).  This is about 4 times faster than if I compile it without specifying optimizations.

Comment: I'll down vote any benchmarking question that doesn't tell how the code is compiled. Really fed up with questions from people who benchmark non-optimized code. Let us know how you compile and I'll retract the down vote.

Comment: Also, you are mainly benchmarking heap allocation times, not the actual algorithm. It's quite possible that the Java VM does something smart with pre-allocation in adjacent memory, while the C malloc calls are fragmented. And you can't benchmark `free` because Java doesn't have that. It will take longer time to free memory in Java, but you don't know when it will get freed, because Java is using a collection of garbage.

Comment: You use `printf()` in C, which has to do format parsing at runtime, while you are using `System.out.println()` in java which does no format parsing.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing oranges to baskets of apples. Did you even take into account that `long` could be *64* bits whereas Java `int` is 32 bits.

Another reason could be that you didn't ask your C compiler to optimize the code. Java *JIT* compiler optimizes the code in time, whereas by *default* GCC does **fast compilation** producing **slow code** for **easy debugging**. There is no JIT optimization. No one **ever** benchmarks unoptimized code, it is as if testing a Ferrari at 20 mph speed limit.

Without any optimizations, I get 3216 milliseconds for Java, 7670 for C for 1000x1000 matrices. With -O3 C running time drops to 2225 ms.

**But it is still oranges to baskets of apples comparison. After I change Java to use `long[][]` then it takes 8300 milliseconds.**

Answer (score 0):

You should compare only multiplication part if you want to find out the matrix multiplication time only ... not its creation, generation, multiplication and deletion. Change your code as

For C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX 10

int main()
{
    // Declaring the variables
    long i, j, k, m1, n1, m2, n2;

    // Reading the dimensions of the matrices
    printf("Enter the row dimension of the matrix 1:\t "); scanf("%ld", &m1);
    printf("Enter the column dimension of the matrix 1:\t "); scanf("%ld", &n1);
    printf("\nEnter the row dimension of the matrix 2:\t "); scanf("%ld", &m2);
    printf("Enter the column dimension of the matrix 2:\t "); scanf("%ld", &n2);

    // Variables used by the clock
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;

    // Necessary condition for matrix multiplication
    if (n1 != m2)
    {
        printf("\nMuliplication is not possible!\n");
        printf("Please check the dimensions of the matrices!\n\n");
    }

    else
    {
        char choice;
        

        long (*mat1)[n1] = malloc(m1 * sizeof *mat1);       // Storing the matrix in heap memory
        if (mat1 == NULL) exit(1);                          // Freeing up space once matrix is NULL
            
        long (*mat2)[n2] = malloc(m2 * sizeof *mat2);
        if (mat2 == NULL) exit(1);
            
        long (*mat3)[n2] = malloc(m1 * sizeof *mat3);
        if (mat3 == NULL) exit(1);

        // Generating matrix with random elements
        for(i=0; i<m1; i++)
            for(j=0; j<n1; j++)
                mat1[i][j] = (long)rand()%MAX;

        // Generating matrix with random elements
        for(i=0; i<m2; i++)
            for(j=0; j<n2; j++)
                mat2[i][j] = (long)rand()%MAX;

    printf("\nMatrices Generated!\n");

        // Initializing the result matrix with zeroes        
        for(i=0; i<m1; i++)
            for(j=0; j<n2; j++)        
                mat3[i][j] = 0;
       start = clock();                                    // Starts the clock
        // Performing mat1[m1][n1] x mat2[m2][n2] = mat3[m1][n2]
        for (i = 0; i < m1; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
                for (k = 0; k < m2; k++)
                    mat3[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
        end = clock();                                                  // Stop the clock timer
        cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;      // Time taken by the program
        printf("\nMultiplication took %f milliseconds to execute.\n\n", cpu_time_used*1000);
        // Freeing up space occupied by the matrices after process completion
        free(mat1); free(mat2); free(mat3);

        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For Java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Matrix {
    private static String s;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        // Reading the dimensions of matrix 1
        System.out.print("Enter the row dimension of the matrix 1:\t ");
        int m1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.print("Enter the column dimension of the matrix 1:\t ");
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        // Reading the dimensions of matrix 2
        System.out.print("\nEnter the row dimension of the matrix 2:\t ");
        int m2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.print("Enter the column dimension of the matrix 2:\t ");
        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        // Print error message if condition not satisfied
        if(n1 != m2) {
            System.out.println("\nMuliplication is not possible!");
            System.out.println("Please check the dimensions of the matrices!\n");
        }

        else {
            
            
            // Declaring matrices
            int[][] matrix1 = new int[m1][n1];
            int[][] matrix2 = new int[m2][n2];

            // Generate random matrices
            generateRandom(matrix1);
            generateRandom(matrix2);

            System.out.println("\nMatrices Generated!\n");
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // Performs matrix1 x matrix2 = result
            int[][] result = new int[m1][n2];
            for (int i = 0; i < m1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < n1; k++) {
                        result[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
                    }
                }
            }
            
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            s = "Execution time is " + (end - start);
            System.out.print(s + " milliseconds.\n\n");
        }
    }

    private static void displayMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        int r = matrix.length;
        int c = matrix[0].length;

        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    // Generates Random Matrices
    private static void generateRandom(int[][] matrix) {
        int r = matrix.length;
        int c = matrix[0].length;
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                // Gives numbers in range (0,10)
                matrix[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have put start and stop time just for matrix multiplication

Comment: Well, given the title of the question this answer is kind of correct. But then one question remains: "why is creation, generation, multiplication and deletion faster in java?"

Comment: You have a mix of stack and heap in C but only heap in java.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no `free` (or `delete`) in Java - it's left to a garbage collector to "clean up" when an object is no longer referenced. Exactly when that happens, we can't tell. Consequently, your Java code isn't doing exactly the same as your C code as the C code has an explicit `free` call. Maybe the compare would be "more fair" if the C code didn't call `free` while the timer is running.

Some other notes:

- Use `calloc` for `mat3` and remove the loop that initializes `mat3`
- Remove all prints in the code that you are using for time measurement (in both C and Java)

At least for the C code, you should also add some prints of the result **after** stopping the timer. This is to prevent a real clever compiler from optimizing all the matrix stuff to "nothing". But notice that you can't do that if you call `free` first.

BTW: I take it for granted that you compile the C code with optimization turned on (e.g. -O3) - if not, it's about time.

Comment: "Make sure to compile the C code with optimization turned on" Come on, we shouldn't need to say this. It's like saying "Make sure the code is compiled by someone who knows programming".

Comment: @Lundin Kind of agree... on the othe hand - SO do get a lot of questions from users that are not really "knowing programming" but rether in the process of learning programming. Anyway - the main point of this answer is that I believe it isn't an apple-to-apple comparision.